# Google Maps V3 on HDPI Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know what might be going on with the Google Maps V3 on HDPI Android devices?  When the map loads on my device it zooms to the appropriate level when first loading, but then pops out of the zoom to a much smaller zoom level[1](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values).  I have changed no code, but this change happened in the last couple days.  I found documentation regarding display of [Google Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values) on HDPI devices and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to correct this issue using v3.

Here are screen shots to show initial and then final:

[image: Initial]

[image]

Comment: Does this happen if you specify an older version of the API? (v3.4 for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem with the latest nightly release of the Maps API. Try specifying v=3.5 when you load the API.